# Test correct SVG component renders with jest and react-testing-library

Tags: reactjs, svg, jestjs, react-testing-library

I have an svg inside a React component that renders conditionally.

```
<div className='avatar'>
      {gender === true ? <MaleAvatar /> : <FemaleAvatar />}
    </div>
```

MaleAvatar and FemaleAvatar are components containing svgs. Initially, I want the MaleAvatar svg to render and then if the value of gender is changed to false the FemaleAvatar svg renders - but the male avatar should render first and that's what I want to test.

The component the conditional is in is a child of a child, but I am testing elements in that component by text and the test works fine eg:

```
const personDetailsText = screen.getByText('Personal details')
```

I am testing with jest and react-testing-library, but using a testing id on the parent div then grabbing the first child doesn't work because it can't recognise the testing id. So if I have:

```
<div data-testid='avatar' className='avatar'>
          {gender === true ? <MaleAvatar /> : <FemaleAvatar />}
        </div>
```

...then the test below fails at 'const avatarSVG = screen.getByTestId('avatar')':

```
test('gender avatar is male on initialisation', () => {
    const avatarSVG = screen.getByTestId('avatar')
    expect(avatarSVG).toBeInTheDocument()
    expect(() => screen.getByTestId('female-avatar').toThrow())
    expect(avatar.firstChild.nodeName).toBe('MaleAvatar')
  })
```

I'm using React hooks and I've read I also need to somehow compensate for React rendering the SVGs after the initial render - after useEffect is finished, but I can't find how to do this with react-testing-library and hooks?

This also does not work:

```
const avatarSVG = document.querySelector('MaleAvatar')
```

How can I grab the SVG components to check the correct one renders?

Comment: Does document.querySelector('.avatar svg') work?

Comment: No unfortunately - it no longer fails on the querySelector tho, now it fails on the expect statement

Comment: Maybe using 'avatar' as both test id and class name is confusing... Did you try it with another class name?

Comment: If I give the parent div a test-id of test-svg-avatar then it fails on     > 61 |     const avatarSVG = screen.getByTestId('test-svg-avatar')

Comment: Another idea: use a shared className (for example 'avatar-icon') for both <MaleAvatar> and <FemaleAvatar> and check if it's present (always should be one)

Comment: I think the queryselector just returns null - svgs are loading after the useEffect hook so jest can't handle them. The common response seems to be to mock them, but I'm not sure how to use jest.mock('../../Assets/SVG/maleAvatar.js', () => () => null)
with a test

Comment: Where are you rendering the component you're testing? It's not visible from your test code.

Comment: do the avatar components use react-svg to inject the svg? if so, you should be aware that xhr requests are involved, that you would have to mock

Comment: If the `data-testid="avatar"` element is rendered async after data loads, then that explains why your syncronous `screen.getByTestId('avatar')` call is failing. Did you try `await screen.findByTestId('avatar')`? More information seems needed to be able to answer this, i.e. a [mcve].

Answer (score 10):

You can view the content of any elements with **screen.debug()**, in your case svg element and according to this content you can use a
selector:

```
import { render, screen } from "@testing-library/react";
screen.debug() // it shows the "dom"
```

In my case, I use **FontAwesomeIcon** and after to use debug I can see:

```html
<svg
            aria-hidden="true"
            class="svg-inline--fa fa-fire fa-w-12 "
            color="#FF9C31"
            data-icon="fire"
            data-prefix="fas"
            focusable="false"
            role="img"
            viewBox="0 0 384 512"
            xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
          >
          
          <path
              d="M216 23.86c0-23.8-30.65-32.77-44.15-13.04C48 191.85 224 200 224 288c0 35.63-29.11 64.46-64.85 63.99-35.17-.45-63.15-29.77-63.15-64.94v-85.51c0-21.7-26.47-32.23-41.43-16.5C27.8 213.16 0 261.33 0 320c0 105.87 86.13 192 192 192s192-86.13 192-192c0-170.29-168-193-168-296.14z"
              fill="currentColor"
            />
          </svg>
```

So, I can use

```
const { container } = render(<MyComponent />);
```

And use some selector in my case `[data-icon='fire']`

```
const svgEl = container.querySelector("[data-icon='fire']") as HTMLImageElement;`
```

It is done, additionally, I can validate if it has a specific class

```
expect(svgEl.classList.toString()).toContain("fa-fire");
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding a `title` prop to each svg? With that, you can use `getByTitle` to assert for svg. Something like

```
<div className='avatar'>
  {gender === true ? <MaleAvatar title="male" /> : <FemaleAvatar title="female" />}
</div>
```

And in your tests

```
expect(getByTitle('male')).toBeInTheDocument();
expect(findByTitle('female')).not.toBeInTheDocument();
```

The second test uses `findByTitle` because if it is not in the document, `getBy*` makes the test fails directly.

Note: to get this approach working, you need to import your SVG files as `ReactComponent` like this:

```
import { ReactComponent as FemaleAvatar } from 'assets/images/FemaleAvatar.svg';
import { ReactComponent as MaleAvatar } from 'assets/images/MaleAvatar.svg';
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found the better way to get svg byTitle
https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytitle/

you need to add title tag in your svg.

so now you can reach your svg: `screen.getByTitle(home icon/ui)`

or you can get some other element by role with svg as its child.

ex. I have a link with svg icon as its child:

```
expect(screen.getByRole('link', { name: /home icon/ui })).toBeInTheDocument();
```

Answer (score -8):

You can put await to find the svg:

```
await screen.getByTestId('id')
```

Comment: `getBy*` queries are not async. Did you mean `findByTestId` instead?

Comment: This query is not user centric. You should not use test-id